# Is there an application indicator for CPU usage by core?

Tags: indicator, cpu-load, system-monitor, multi-core

I love System Load Indicator (indicator-multiload), but it doesn't reflect the usage of the individual CPU cores, just the overall CPU usage.  Sometimes I'll have an application max out a single core (ahem, Eclipse), but when I glance at the CPU usage graph, everything looks acceptable.

I know I can just open Htop, but the whole point of an application indicator is being able to get the information you want with a glance, not keystrokes.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried conky?

Comment: Is there a way to make conky display as an indicator?

Comment: Yes I know about gnome-system-monitor too, and it does show usage per core, but that's not an indicator application, is it? I still miss the huge advantage of showing that information with Unity at the top of your screen, like you do have with Gnome.

Comment: @JasonHartley Yes you can use Conky. I've posted an answer below for you to see on your next semi-annual visit to AskUbuntu :)

Answer (score 2):

This is for Ubuntu 14.04 and later.

1. Install `indicator-sysmonitor`

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
   ```
2. Run it
3. Click on its indicator → Preferences → Advanced tab
4. Change label from `cpu: {cpu} mem: {mem}` to `cpu: {cpu0}{cpu1} mem: {mem}`. Add whatever as CPU cores you have.
5. Save

   [image: indicator-sysmonitor: cpu cores usage indicator]

References:

- [Ubuntu AppIndicator That Displays Bash Scripts Output On The Panel: Sysmonitor Indicator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html)

Answer (score 2):

System Monitor, aka "Conky" is a well known light-weight system monitor popular across most Linux distributions. On an Intel i-7 Core you can display all 8 CPUs:

[image: Conky CPUs]

The relevant code to make this is:

```
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® i-7 3630QM 3.4 GHz: ${color1}@  ${color green}${freq} MHz   
${color}${goto 13}CPU 1 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu1 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 2 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu2}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu2 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 3 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu3}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu3 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 4 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu4}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu4 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 5 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu5}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu5 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 6 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu6}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu6 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 7 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu7}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu7 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 8 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu8}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu8 18}
${color1}All CPU ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 2 temp 1}°C ${goto 250}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
${color green}$running_processes ${color1}running of ${color green}$processes ${color1}loaded processes.
```

Posting the entire conky configuration file isn't possible because it is too long and it contains too many test sections making it unprofessional. You can google conky samples and find one that appeals to you. Then you can copy and paste the above code into the one you found.

Answer (score 1):

After Sitting, and looking at the code of indicator-multiload, I managed to make it.

**I made the code for 4 cores. If you have more it will only show the first 4 cores**

Go to */usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/* and search for 
*de.mh21.indicator-multiload.gschema.xml* Replace the code within the file with [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5aypgfd4hotqhv/4_cores.gschema.xml.txt?dl=0)

Apply changes by typing into the terminal:

> sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/

In my case, I had to reboot:

> sudo reboot

---

When done, go to  *indicator-multiload > preferences > advanced*
Select "custom1" and replace *$cpu.inuse* with *$cpu.cpu0.inuse*
 
Then Select "custom2" and replace *$cpu.inuse* with *$cpu.cpu1.inuse*
 
Then Select "custom3" and replace *$cpu.inuse* with *$cpu.cpu2.inuse*
 
Then Select "custom4" and replace *$cpu.inuse* with *$cpu.cpu3.inuse*

Select For each your desired color.

Thanks to mook765, the links should work now!

Comment: When I open the link, I get `The owner of 82.95.67.85 has configured their website improperly`,  please include essential parts in your answer and use links as reference only. A broken link could make your answer useless.

Comment: @Emanuel-maat If you are the same person that wrote that answer please use *contact us* at the bottom of this page to get your accounts merged.

Answer (score 0):

for indicator-multiload's "menu-items" you can add cpu frequency and load:

preferences > menu-items > add

$(frequency(cpufreq.cur0)) - $(percent(cpu.cpu0.inuse))

$(frequency(cpufreq.cur1)) - $(percent(cpu.cpu1.inuse))

...

it's still one extra click.. but at least easily available

Answer (score -1):

Gnome System Monitor shows system load per core for me,

It should have come with your installation, but if not then:
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor

resources tab

Comment: He wants an *app indicator*, not app...